# SPD-Slogan „Das WIR entscheidet“

Tags: meaning, pronoun, article, grammar-identification

Ich versuche zu verstehen, was der Slogan der SPD bedeutet, aber es scheint, dass es sprachlich nicht so einfach ist.

Ich zitiere aus dem [Regierungsprogramm der SPD 2013–2017](http://www.spd.de/95466/regierungsprogramm_2013_2017.html):

> Wir wollen ein Land, in dem Wohlstand und Zukunftschancen fair verteilt sind. Ein Land, in dem das wir entscheidet und nicht bloß Gier und Eigennutz.

Meine Fragen sind:

- Worauf bezieht sich *das* in dem Satz „in dem das wir entscheidet“?
- Wieso ist der Satz nicht „in dem **das das wir** entscheidet“ oder „in dem das **uns** entscheidet“?

Comment: On campaign posters that slogan was sometimes altered to “Das Bier entscheidet” (or a similar pun) by pranksters / vandals.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Du bist (vermutlich) über einen Rechtschreibfehler gestolpert (gemäß § 57 (3) der Rechtschreibregeln). Eigentlich müsste da stehen:

> ein Land, in dem das **W**ir entscheidet

*Wir* ist hier ein substantiviertes Pronomen und *das* der zugehörige Artikel. Eine weitgehend wörtliche Übersetzung ins Englische ist:

> a country in which the “we” decides

Hätten sie einfach nur »in dem wir entscheiden« geschrieben, wäre nicht klar gewesen, ob sich *wir* die Angesprochenen beinhaltet. Es hätte also missverstanden werden können als »in dem die SPD entscheidet«.

Answer (score 0):

Man kann vermuten, daß die Werbeleute, die sich das ausgedacht haben, die Analogie zu *das Ich* im Auge hatten. Das ist ja in der Psychologie und Gehirnforschung ein üblicher Begriff. Im Sinne des zitierten Textes stünde dann das Ich für Gier und Eigennutz und andere unschöne Dinge, und im Kontrast sorgt dann das Wir für faire Verteilung usw.

Wie oft bei solchen Marketingtexten ist es zweifelhaft, ob solche Sprüche, die möglicherweise von den Autoren als "kreativ" angesehen werden, bei den Lesern positiv ankommen.

Comment: Schöne Vermutung, geht aber meines Erachtens am Text der Frage vorbei.